# Meteor autoform, async callback in before hook

Tags: meteor, meteor-slingshot

I am using Autoform and Slingshot for my S3 interaction. When the user submits the form, i want to intercept the process, upload the file to S3 through Slingshot, extend the `doc` object with the returned `downloadUrl` and then at that point, return the new updated doc, and continue the autoform process

I have the following code:

```
{{#autoForm collection="Tabs" id="newTabForm" type="method" meteormethod="createTab"}}

   ...
    <div class="modal-body">
      <fieldset>
         {{> afFormGroup name='downloadUrl' type='file' class='file-bag'}}
    ...

AutoForm.hooks({
  newTabForm: {
    before: {
      insert: function(doc, template) {
        console.log(doc);
        var file     = $('.file-bag')[0].files[0];

        var self = this;
        uploader.send(file, function(error, downloadUrl) {
          if (error) { throw new Meteor.Error(error); }

          doc = _.extend(doc, { downloadUrl: downloadUrl });
          self.result(doc);
        });
      }
    },
 ....

Meteor.methods({
createTab: function(doc) {
  check(doc, TabSchema);

  var priceInCents = doc.price * 100;
  var extraTabAttributes = {
    userId: Meteor.userId(),
    price: priceInCents
  };

  _.extend(doc, extraTabAttributes);
  Tabs.insert(doc, function(error, result) {
    if (error) { return error; }
  });
}
```

Which correctly stores url (however looks weird, C://fakepath/filename..) on the document, but fails to upload it to the S3 server

Also side question, why doesnt the `console.log(doc);` in the before hooks log anything to the client/server?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? Was looking for a solution for using autoform with slingshot. I haven't yet got very far though.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with auto form but I think your before hook is incorrect.

From https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks , it said

```
before: {

  // Replace `formType` with the form `type` attribute to which this hook applies
  formType: function(doc) {}

}
```

So in your case,

```
insert: function(doc, template)
```

Should be replaced with

```
method: function(doc, template)
```